# Multiple language website with google translate api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, google-translate

Hello
I want to make my site displayed in different languages. I had idea to use Google Translate API. Is it good method or it will make site slow? Is it compatible with jQuery? If it's a bad solution can any expert of web development explain or give a link of good article, of better metod to translate whole site?

Comment: I don't consider this being a problem nor a question. Downvoted due to lack of research.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the output of Google Translate?  It's fine when you *know* you're looking at something translated by machine, but it gets all sorts of things terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i can see, answered peoples already told you that google translate is not best choice. I suggest you make your own language file (.php) and let the user choose which language to use. But if you wanna that with google api, when try this: http://translateth.is/

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate is all around a bad idea. Hire someone (find a friend) who speaks the languages your interested in targeting and have them do the translation. Heaven forbid you let Google do it and your English expression becomes a Swedish insult.

Here's some articles to get you started (though I'm not sure what backend tech you're using):

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/MultilingualJSP/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multilanguageapplications.aspx